# Convert a string list to a tuple in Python

Tags: python, string, tuples

I am trying to convert a string such as `'SUP E P I C'` to a tuple containing all the non-spaced strings. For example, if the input is `'SUP E P I C'`, then the program should return `('S', 'U', 'P', 'E', 'P', 'I', 'C')` and I am trying the obvious method of looping, and I started as follows:

```
for ch in john:
    if ch != ' ':
        j1 += ch
    else:
        # stuff
```

I'm stuck because I can add the first entry of the tuple but after that skipping the space is just escaping me. Any hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: The only problem with your code is that `j1 += ch` won't work if `j1` is a `tuple` and `ch` is a string. gnibbler's solution is clearer and simpler, and maybe even faster, but your solution is fine, except for this one problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

tuples are immutable, so building them up one item at a time is very inefficient. You can pass a sequence directly to `tuple`

```
>>> tuple('SUP E P I C'.replace(" ",""))
('S', 'U', 'P', 'E', 'P', 'I', 'C')
```

or use a generator expression (overkill for this example)

```
>>> tuple(x for x in 'SUP E P I C' if not x.isspace())
('S', 'U', 'P', 'E', 'P', 'I', 'C')
```

Comment: Excellent, just what I was looking for; thanks a lot! I'll upvote/accept once my vote lock and accept lock get free. :)

Comment: Sorry, one more question - what if we wanted to replace more than one thing? For example, if we wanted to replace the spaces with blanks (like you did) but *also* new-line characters with blanks, what might we do then?

Comment: @AhaanRungta, the second version will filter any whitespace. You could also use `tuple('SUP E P I C'.translate(None, ' \n'))`

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. :) Accepted. But I'll have to wait 12 more minutes to upvote.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that you're trying to add a string to a tuple; you need to add a tuple to a tuple:

```
j1 = ()
for ch in john:
    if ch != ' ':
        j1 += (ch,)
```

With that one little fix, your original code works.

And it's equivalent to the comprehension given in gnibbler's answer:

```
j1 = tuple(ch for ch in john if ch != ' ')
```

… or, for that matter, a `filter`call:

```
j1 = tuple(filter(lambda ch: ch != ' ', john))
```

Except, of course, that if that "other stuff" is anything non-trivial, you won't be able to easily convert it; you'll need to stick with your original explicit loop. And there's nothing wrong with that.